# filling the zero elements in an array with the closest previous nonzero element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

[image]

I am working with a data array `A` which has the following behaviour when plotted. As one can see, there are some "isles" in the middle. In those areas, the `A` array is zero. It is assured that the remaining values are nonzero, even if on the order of `1e-9`.

What I would like to do is to make the function "continuous", meaning I would like to substitute the zero values with the nonzero value that the array had before becoming zero.

Is there a fast general way this could be implemented?  This is the first example I got, but future results may involve even more "isles".

I tried using `np.where`, but it does not seem to support a command such as "if zero, substitute with previous nonzero value in array". Or at least, I don't know how to do that.

If so, how could I write in in code?

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: Do you have the codes to reproduce that graph?

Comment: Do you ever have negative values? Will the filled arrays always be monotonically non-decreasing, as in your example?

Comment: Please show also the desired result.

Comment: if you need just plot data - you can get rid of zeros by `A[A > 1e-9]`

Comment: Unfortunately the code I am using is a bit involved, as this is only a part of series of things that I am trying to simulate. I will code a mock example and make it look tidier, but I will need some time.

Comment: Could you answer the questions about the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a data array `a` you could do this:

```
while np.any(a==0):
    indices=np.where(a==0)
    newvalueindices=np.subtract(indices,np.ones_like(indices))
    a[indices]=a[newvalueindices]
```

If you would like to avoid loops, here is another,faster solution:

```
zeroindices=np.where(a==0)
nonzeroindices=np.where(a!=0)
missingfrom=np.searchsorted(nonzeroindices[0],zeroindices[0])
previndices=np.subtract(missingfrom,np.ones_like(missingfrom))
a[zeroindices]=a[nonzeroindices][previndices]
```

Comment: Is that really "fast"? Looks like up to quadratic time to me.

Comment: At least according to [my test](https://tio.run/##XU7bCsMgDH33K3xUkNGtuzHwS0oZWReorEtF7Ypf78S2MJYQwrmF2Bj6keqUzNuOLnCa3jZy8JwsY8B13jtwDqJo9uqgqtJ1nqM6qfOKK3VR11Yy6wwFAZKxuTcDlixFAVpX8sZ4LkNP06HXWZl7dLhoRSKcPzBM@GPx0yM46IJYOZW5kdDfB/PCjZRLHJoVtxqav1ttcWzfpfQF).

Comment: well I don't know how big arrays is it necessary to work with. But with one dimensional arrays, even if they are huge, i think it is quite good.

Comment: Took [16 seconds](https://tio.run/##XYzdCgIhEEbvfQovV4gwopvAJxGJaRtYyR3Fn2R7ebN2g@i7GeacmS8sefJ0bM3OwcfMqcxh4ZA4BcaAqz73T4w@DSfZIxhoaTo@MFYn6/DtgZYBlJLizHiPpZsdMalu6oQRV/dRhPUBruDPSSrXHGHMw8Z2nXnCdHH2jl8o1nfQ224U6L8u09oL) for an array of size 50000.

Comment: well testing it with a zeros array it is obviously much slower, but i feel like thats not really a reasonable input. [link](https://tio.run/##XYzLCsIwEEX3@YosEygSUDdCvqQUGetAg@kk5GGpPx/Th6DO5jLnPvycBkfHUszoXUic8uhnDpGTZwy4rnoIQHc3rmIoiZNqonmhPqt6kvmwQIskanQaMKAArZVsVSclY9NgLC4rQPNmXBivZ@pYj1H/llaLcHqCzfgVifmWAvRJ7KypzBHGqzUP/EC51aHd/05D@7fVlfIG)

Comment: Seems more realistic to me than your random data example, which most of the time has only two consecutive zeros. The OP's image does look like they have thousands of consecutive zeros.

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##XY/dCoMwDIXv@xSdVwoyqptjCH0SkZFtGZZpLG2duJd3rVMYy0XC@U5@iJ5c09NhnlWne@M4DZ2eOFhOmjHg0te9Abr33VIUufgoUqveKAvhI2FQZUKUWSFqKYLIiyAPPq8g9JXZSWwgX0B@XgEbG9ViuAM0xSClSErGfSh/7oZWemds0ODXWyzC8QXtgD8tdrg6AzcXryz1rCe0l1Y9cYPJdxyqVdcSqr9dNdMmfBk9FCnb4H0XJfP8AQ) it is with a bunch of consecutive zeros

Comment: I inserted said routine into the code and it seem to work, I am only wondering howvere if a loop won't slow down the calculations in a consistent way, or if it can be written in a more compact way (maybe using np.where() ? ). Despite this, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I improved the answer with a loopless solution

Comment: Why not `previndices=missingfrom-1`?